Can I affect shape keys using "Vertex weight modifier"?
I am trying to affect shape keys using a Vertex Weight Proximity modifier, trying to emulate Morpher & Volume Select in 3dsmax
The issue in Blender is that the shape keys are not responding to the Vertex Weight Proximity modifier. They react only when I directly paint using the brush in weight paint.
Is there any way I can make the facade react to the empty which is linked to the Vertex Weight Proximity modifier?

Issue shown in the video linked

Check out https://blenderartists.org/t/control-shape-keys-using-proximity/1355629 .  That was written before GN and still works, but GN opens up some alternate techniques.

Maybe the simplest way to go for this case is to implement Shape Keys in Geometry Nodes, to push that up into the right place in the pipeline.
A Shape Key is a linear mix between the positions of points with corresponding indices:

.. here controlled by distance from a selected controller object, with adjustable Max and Min thresholds..

The output includes the mix-factor per vertex to be passed down the stack,  used in a shader, and so forth.
This could be refined, e.g. ensuring mix-factor per element, rather than per-vertex, or controlling by aspects of controller geometry rather than distance, etc.


Thanks! it actually worked, although the only issue is the controller affects mesh only when the controller's  origin touches it. I have linked the image                https://imgur.com/a/LQKYVr8

Hi, @SushrithSNayak!   Have you changed the min and max values? If no luck, share a representative .blend on https://blend-exchange.com/ , and I'll check it out. Also, check the object-level scaling of all your objects ..

Yes, I did change the values, still the same, I will share the file then, Thanks again!


@SushrithSNayak  Strange.. works for me.. OK.. I removed the modifier, checked that it worked as shape-keys, removed the shape keys again, re-assigned the modifier .. https://imgur.com/a/eUr79ym . I've renamed some stuff to be sure what's up in the file. (sorry) and added a driver to the display size of the Empty controller so it actually shows the maximum size of the effect. Here's the file. Hope it's OK.

@SushrithSNayak ahh OK, you changed these values, I think. Of course, you can do that, to change the fall-off, or put the 0-1 output value as set in the illustration through a Float Curve node to change the shape of the falloff

That was super helpful! Thank you so much @Robin Betts, It is working great now
